# Best place to put registration fields?

Tags: forms, login, registration

I have a form that will allow a user to post a classified listing on my site. The thing is, we required users to be signed in to post...so instead of redirecting a user to a separate page to sign in or register, I would like to include the sign in / register fields WITHIN my posting form, and save them a step or two.

1. how do you feel about that idea?
2. where in the form is the right place to put the sign in / register fields? a complete list of the fields on that page are as follows:

display name [if registering]
email
password

title
description
price
upload images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its a great idea and having first (like you wrote) is the best way. You don't want a user being surprised after they filled out the form that they must sign up and then decide if they want to sign up.

Alternatively, I would recommend trying to implement [OpendID](http://openid.net/), [facebookID](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/), and [TwitterID](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter) log in systems. You're registrations will go up and for your type of website it makes more sense. Users tire of making accounts for a site they use sparingly.

Comment: Totally feeling putting it at top. As for the other logins, we have an issue in that multiple users often need to access a single account. I haven't been able to find a way to use FB (which is our first choice) work in that scenario.

Comment: Go for it, I really think that is the best UX choice.

Answer (score 2):

Not leaving the site sounds good. How about linking an website overlay (greyed out background) containing the registration/login form to the publish-button? That would only show up if one is not registered or logged in? Redundantly I would provide a login/register feature on the websites top.

-- Changed opinion after comment discussion. See mini wireframe. No popup. But the form hidden behind the publish button. The button greys out until sucessfull login.

[image]

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but there are also places where the posting form will appear as a modal window itself...making it kinda strange to have two show up (one for sign in, and one for posting)

Comment: Also...I'd really like it to not feel like a "step". I'd almost want them to not realize they just registered.

Comment: True: a popup over a popup is not really elegant. I'd then suggest to flip your proposed positions. First the input of content. Publish Button will open (fast animation) the registration or login form below the content. The publish button also will be now greyed out until sucessful registration or login.

Comment: Sweet, that wireframe really helps me get whatcha mean. I'm going to try both your idea and @jonshariats idea and see which kinda flows better!

Answer (score 0):

you may also consider a 'collapsible form', something that expands below a certain field, or the white space next to the form, and then collapses again when the form is filled up.

(sorry if i'm not making sense, or that i can't give you an example.  i'm new to ux, still learning a lot.)